# iCloud without Provisioning Profiles

Tags: macos, icloud, provisioning-profile

I would like to build an OS X app with iCloud integration just as a learning experience. Is there a way of doing this without being enrolled in any of apple's developer programs?

Answer (score 1):

Apple requires that you enroll in the developer program to use iCloud.

Answer (score 1):

Each app on your iDevice has one folder for iCloud-storage. And these folders are different. Their name depends on their app-bundle-ID (such as: com.company.myapp ...)

So, if you don't use provisioning profile (or provisioning profile has name: com.company.*), how iCloud know folder of your app!

Its logic is that!

Good luck!